# In Joomla article: How to load a module while hovering on a link

Tags: joomla, module

I'm working on a Joomla website with a slider in it. I'm using {loadposition slider1}, to get the slider (slider 1) in an article. There is a text link beneath the slider. Now I'd like the page to load another slider (slider 2), in the position of slider 1 when someone hovers over the text link. So visitors hovering the link will see slider 2 in stead of slider 1 when hovering the link.

Can I do this by using javascript? I haven't  been able to find a solution. I hope someone can help me with this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Joomla! the `{loadposition slider1}` tag in articles is processed by a content plug-in when an event is triggered. Usually `onContentPrepare` or similar event. The important part of this is that it's all done on the server before it reaches the users browser.

As it's processed in the article there is no way to call the server again and request just `slider 2`...

To swap in your `slider2` would require the browser to already have it available.  To achieve this you could have `{loadposition slider2}` in a `<div>` or other element in the article that is set to `display:none`. eg.

```
<div id="slider2" style="display:none;">{loadposition slider2}</div>
```

*NB. this is not necessarily good html...*

This means when the browser receives the article html, it contains the element it's just hidden, then you can use the your javascript to hide `slider1` and show `slider2` when the user hovers over the link.